# Dynamic constant assignment in Ruby

Tags: ruby, constants

Shown below is a ruby code.

```
def parse_file(file)
  parsed_data = {}
  TOTAL = []
  Maths = []
  Physics = []
  Chemistry = []
  read_lines(file) { |line|
    arr=l.split
    if l.match(/TOTAL/i)
      TOTAL = arr[1].to_i
    end
    if l.match(/maths/i)
      Maths = arr[1].to_i
    end
    if l.match(/physics/i)
      Physics = arr[1].to_i
    end
    if l.match(/chemistry/i)
      Chemistry = arr[1].to_i
    end
  }
  if TOTAL != Maths + Physics + Chemistry && TOTAL != 0
    parsed_data[:not_matched] = "True"
  end
  return parsed_data
end
```

It gives multiple "dynamic constant assignment" errors:

```
-:3: dynamic constant assignment
      TOTAL = []
             ^
-:4: dynamic constant assignment
      Maths = []
             ^
-:5: dynamic constant assignment
      Physics = []
               ^
-:6: dynamic constant assignment
      Chemistry = []
                 ^
-:10: dynamic constant assignment
          TOTAL = arr[1].to_i
                 ^
-:13: dynamic constant assignment
          Maths = arr[1].to_i
                 ^
-:16: dynamic constant assignment
          Physics = arr[1].to_i
                   ^
-:19: dynamic constant assignment
          Chemistry = arr[1].to_i
                     ^
```

What change can I make so that it won't affect my intention?

Comment: I've never encountered this error before and I'm quite surprised that Ruby fails with a `SyntaxError`. I would have expected the usual "already initialized constant" warning when running the code.

Comment: @Stefan I think that they want to make it a `SyntaxError` if it is detectable during parsing stage.

Comment: @sawa sure, detecting code inconsistencies early on is a great aid. But raising a *syntax* error seems a bit harsh IMO. Furthermore, it even forbids code like `Foo = 1 unless defined? Foo` within a method.

Comment: Aside from using constant names as variable names, this code is very strange. The variables are initialized to empty arrays but then set to be integers.

Answer (score 4):

Change it to a local variable, for example `total`.

Answer (score 3):

The error says "dynamic constant assignment". CAPITAL_LETTERS are treated as constants and must not be dynamically assigned new values in the code.

Therefore, its best for you to change the `TOTAL` to a local variable like `total`

Comment: Your answer is contradictory. By definition, variables are not constants, constants are not variables.